# VLC WebPlugin with Subtitles

Tags: plugins, vlc

Im using the VLC WebPlugin to show videos on my website. I need to know if webplugin can support subtitles loaded by a specific url.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the VLC plugin to IE and Mozilla can display a subtitle track accompanying a video stream (the 2 get streamed together). You do not say whether the subtitles are coming from the same URL as the video stream, or a different URL. If the latter, then no this won't work - only one URL gets passed to VLC (with or without accompanying subtitles). The video encoder putting out the video stream may be capable of taking an external feed for the subtitles, but this happens at source and not at the client end.

Hope that helps :)